# how to compare two hashmaps and display true for the same values?

Tags: java

i have written a program for two hashmaps which has same keys but different values

Session Key and Values
1 : red
2 : green
3 : blue
4 : violet

Database Key and Values
1 : gray
2 : pink
3 : blue
4 : black

what i want to achieve is compare both hashmaps values and list everything but the ones with the same values should be displayed as true 
like this 
1 red grey false
2 green pink false
3 blue blue true
4 violet black false

ClassComparator.java : i have just written this program to print the values of both the hashmaps , please i need some assistance to solve the further query.

```
public class ClassComparator {

Map<Integer, String> sessionValues;
Map<Integer, String> dbValues;
Map<Integer, String> combineKeyValues;

public ClassComparator() {
    // /////popuulate session Values
    combineKeyValues = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    sessionValues = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    sessionValues.put(1, "red");
    sessionValues.put(2, "green");
    sessionValues.put(3, "blue");
    sessionValues.put(4, "violet");
    System.out.println("Session Values : " + sessionValues);
    dbValues = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    dbValues.put(1, "gray");
    dbValues.put(2, "pink");
    dbValues.put(3, "blue");
    dbValues.put(4, "black");
    System.out.println("Database Values : " + dbValues);
    System.out.println("");
}

public List<QuestionResult> compareValues() {
    List<QuestionResult> results = new ArrayList<QuestionResult>();

    // /// comparison logic
    System.out.println("Session Key and Values");
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> sessionEntry : sessionValues.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(sessionEntry.getKey() + " : " + 
        sessionEntry.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Database Key and Values");
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> dbEntry : dbValues.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(dbEntry.getKey() + " : " + dbEntry.getValue());
    }

    return results;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ClassComparator cc = new ClassComparator();
    cc.compareValues();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need 2 separate loop. Iterate over the first map, and get the value for that key from the other map too, and compare them.

Sample code:

```
Map<Integer, String> firstMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Map<Integer, String> secondMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

for (Entry<Integer, String> firstEntry : firstMap.entrySet()) {
  String firstMapValue = firstEntry.getValue();
  String secondMapValue = secondMap.get(firstEntry.getKey());
  System.out.println(firstEntry.getKey() + " " + firstMapValue + " " + secondMapValue + " " + firstMapValue.equals(secondMapValue));
}
```